# Deleting a database row when delete link is clicked

Tags: php, hyperlink, click, html-table, delete-row

The following PHP script is used to retrieve a set of data (order numbers) in my database

```
<?php
            require("includes/db.php");

            $sql="SELECT * FROM `order` ";
            $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
echo"<head>";
echo'
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="view.css">
            <head>


        ';
echo"</head>";

echo "<body >";
echo "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=4 > " ;
echo"<tr bgcolor=grey>";
echo"<td align=center>";
echo "<font size=4>";
echo "<B>";
echo "Order No.";
echo "</B>";
echo"</td>";
echo"</tr>";


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    echo"<tr>";
     echo"<td align=center>";
    echo $row["OrderNo."];
     echo "<br>";
     echo"</td>";
    echo"<td align=center>";
    echo "<a href='delete.php?del=";
    echo $row['OrderNo.'];
    echo">delete</a>";
     echo "<br>";
     echo"</td>";
    echo"</tr>";
}
    echo"</table>";

?>
```

When the delete link in each ow is clicked that specific row must be deleted! The PHP script for deletion is as follows

```
< ?php
     include("includes/db.php");

    if( isset($_GET['del']) )
    {
        $id = $_GET['del'];
        $sql= "DELETE FROM order WHERE OrderNo.='$id'";
        $res= mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die("Failed".mysql_error());

    }
?>
```

I did not redirect the 2nd PHP script to the initial one in order to identify the error! when the delete link is clicked i get the following on the screen with out any deletion of the row!

```
< ?php 
    include("includes/db.php"); 
    if( isset($_GET['del']) ) { 
        $id = $_GET['del']; 
        $sql= "DELETE FROM order WHERE OrderNo.='$id'"; 
        $res= mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die("Failed".mysql_error()); 
    } 
?>
```

How can I rectify this in order to delete a row when its delete link is clicked?

Comment: Look at your first query vs your second and the word `order` specifically. You also are open to SQL injections, use parameterized queries. `SELECT * FROM \`order\`` == correct. `DELETE FROM order` == invalid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Comment: Also `mysql_error` doesn't work with `mysqli`.

Comment: What is your column name? "OrderNo" or "OrderNo." (ie with a dot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$sql= "DELETE FROM `order` WHERE `OrderNo.` = '$id' ";
```

Also Something wrong with html table row. You have not closed the single quote(') before delete. Please try with below code.

```
echo "<td align=center>";
echo "<a href='delete.php?del=";
echo $row['OrderNo.'];
echo "'>delete</a>";
echo "<br>";
echo"</td>";
```

Comment: nope its still not working ! i still get the error "failed"!

Comment: if i am to delete that row and transfer the values to another table how can i do it?

Comment: Before delete, you have insert the row from this table to another. INSERT INTO Table2(Column21, Column22 ,...)
SELECT Column11, Column12,... FROM  `order` WHERE `OrderNo.` = '$id' ";

Comment: now there are 2 sql queries on the same php script! do i need to execute mysqli_query() method twice? creating 2 variables?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$sql= "DELETE FROM order WHERE OrderNo = '".$id."'";
```

Comment: no error occurs ! only the 2nd php script  appears on the web browser! like echoin a certain string in php

Comment: Integers don't need to be quoted.

Comment: can you explain what you getting actual mysqli_error()?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order WHERE OrderNo. = '1>delete
2

Comment: @Amal What is your column name? "OrderNo" or "OrderNo." i thinks you added extra dot after OrderNo

Answer (score 0):

your second code says it all.
change `< ?php` to `<?php`. you are misidentifying the file as a php a script in the first place.

Comment: thanx now its identified as a php file but when i click delete i get the fail message that means there is still an error :(

Comment: you are not getting the error because you are using `mysql_error()` with the `MySQLi` extension. replace `mysql_error` with `mysqli_error($db)`

Comment: thanx now i get the error! You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order WHERE OrderNo. = '1>delete

Comment: how can i coorect this?

Comment: A dot in a column name could be an issue try this `WHERE \`OrderNo.\` = '$id'` as others suggested.